# .NET Core 2: Force authentication handler to run before middleware?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core-2.0

Ripping api endpoints out of a .NET Core 1 web project to a .NET Core 2 api-only project. My experience with auth (both -orization and -entication) is minimal at best, mainly because most projects I've worked on have already been setup for auth and/or it's been an AD environment.

The API portion of the site uses a pre-shared token to be included in the header of every request. This token is the key to all auth, user identification, permissions, etc etc. The user info (ie. who are you and what can you do) is contained in a custom `CurrentContext` class.

The Core 1 project uses middleware (`ContextMiddleware`) to init the `CurrentContext` instance that is registered in DI as `scoped`. By the time the `ContextMiddleware` class is called, the custom auth handler has already been called, the necessary header token has already been examined, authentication checks have passed, and a principal has been created. Thus, the `ContextMiddleware` class, which heavily depends on the principal existing, can build the `CurrentContext` and the truckload of information needed to know who's calling.

The Core 2 project ends up running `ContextMiddleware` before the authentication handler, and I can't figure out how to force the order of those two to swap.

Relevant code snippets:

```
public class Startup {
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
        // ...
        // https://geeklearning.io/how-to-migrate-your-authentication-middleware-to-asp-net-core-2-0/
        services.AddAuthentication( options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = UserTokenAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        } ).AddUserTokenAuthentication(UserTokenAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, 
                                       UserTokenAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                                       o => { } );

        // ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app /*...*/) {
        if (env.IsDevelopment()){
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        } else {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/error/500");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMiddleware<ContextMiddleware>();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

If more code snippets are needed for further information, please let me know. How do I force my auth handler's HandleAuthenticateAsync() to run *before* `ContextMiddleware` is invoked?

Comment: Hello, Have you tried changing the order of the .UseXXX() calls ?
It seems like the right order but you maybe have something else interfering. It would be better if you gave the whole startup/program files.
Thanks

Comment: This is an old question, but we're having a similar issue in Core 3.1. Have you figured out what the solution was? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this too and we found it best to support a "dynamic" authentication scheme we made up that then allows a selector to be called to make the authentication type decision.

Add a `DynamicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme = "Dynamic";` constant somewhere in your codebase per ASP.NET Core standards, then in your startup class' `ConfigureServices` add the dynamic scheme:

```
.AddAuthentication( options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = DynamicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = DynamicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = DynamicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = DynamicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignOutScheme = DynamicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
} )
.AddYourCustomAuthentication( YourCustomAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, YourCustomAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => { } )
.AddPolicyScheme( DynamicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, DynamicAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.ForwardDefaultSelector = DynamicAuthenticationSchemaSelector.Evaluate;
} );
```

then in a custom `DynamicAuthenticationSchemaSelector` class implement that evaluation method:

```
public static class DynamicAuthenticationSchemaSelector
{
    public static string Evaluate( HttpContext context )
    {
        string result;

        var authHeader = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();

        if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( authHeader ) && authHeader.StartsWith( YourCustomAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme ) )
        {
            result = YourCustomAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }
        else
        {
            result = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

You'll get the proper authentication middleware handling.

You don't need to call this "dynamic" either and it's just for following best practices / patterns -- any string will suffice.